# What happened to the organization creating and enslaving mutants in Deadpool (the movie)?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, deadpool, deadpool-2016

What happens to the mystery organization that creates and enslaves mutants?

> This workshop doesn't make superheroes, we make superslaves. 
>   We're gonna fit you with a control collar and auction you off to the highest bidder.

Ajax was a patient at the facility suggesting that he is not the head of the organization; although he brokers deals and is in command of Angel.

> I'm about to hurt you, Wade. I was a patient here once myself, you know.

At the end of the movie, Ajax is dead along with Agent Smith, a bunch of goons and everyone on Wade's giant web of photographs.

#### Did Deadpool kill his way through the entire organization or are they still out there?

Comment: He blew up the facility (killing everyone inside) and then murdered his way through the organisation to get to Ajax. The fact that he's crossed off every one of the photographs would strongly suggest that the front end of the organisation is dead. That being said, someone was presumably *financing* the chop-shop and providing them with the experimental chemicals needed to provoke the mutagenic reaction and there's no sign that they aren't still around, getting ready for the sequel.

Comment: Even if the mysterious backers got away, i'd like to know if Deadpool was able to get everyone else.

Comment: "*Everyone else"* was simply a means to an end. His primary goal wasn't to tear the organisation apart, it was to get to Ajax. He probably let a few people get away if he sensed that they were no use to him.

Comment: There will be a sequel. So, we will watch it and we will know what was happened

Comment: Fair enough, I was hoping there was some info available outside of the movie

Comment: The movie doesn't mention if the organisation is completely destroyed or not, but in the comic version Ajax works for a secretive programme developing mutants as weapons called "Weapon X". As this programme is a covert operation of the U.S and Canadian goverments, if it's the same one in the movie then it's possible it still exists in some form.

Answer (score 3):

The organization is Weapon X. Which is a US government genetic research project. So they will have multiple black sites of which Deadpool destroys one. They would have very little to do with one another so there is a possibility that it was either rogue or its higher power is nefarious and "auctioning" there creations off to fund other projects.

Edit - In the comics Ajax(Francis Freeman) worked for Dr. Killebrew.
Source "A Kiss, A Curse, A Cure" 1998 Annual Starring Deadpool and Death (July 1998)

Comment: Do you have a source for it being Weapon X within the XCU? The project was never mentioned in the movie.

Comment: Have updated with source. But your right given the nature of different origin stories and how they change things up between movies and comics, this could be another agency. Without a second movie we can only speculate using the comics and this fits everything.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it has satisfied my curiosity

Comment: Eh, in the comics, Negasonic Teenage Warhead had vastly different powers, and the XCU has played fast and loose with origin stories not matching up. Ajax and the organization are definitely *based* on Weapon X, but that isn't proof that it is within the XCU.

Comment: 100% agree phantom42, but there isnt anything else to go on, unless someone has buddies on the inside :).

Comment: In the movie, Francis specifically says that the organisation is a private company and **not the government**.